# Need to connect mac-mini and thunderbolt display to a Dell U2713HM for dual monitor 2560x1440

Tags: mac-mini, hdmi, resolution, thunderbolt-display

I need to run a dual 27" 2560x1440 mac-mini. I already have a thunderbolt display and I tried connecting a Dell Ultrasharp with 2560x1440 to the HDMI port of the mac mini - that doesn't work.  There is a spare Thunderbolt port on the back of the Apple display, so do I use that and connect to the Dell?  If so, what port on the Dell do I use to get the full resolution - HDMI, DVI, Ethernet?

Answer (score 1):

HDMI is out because the Mac Mini's HDMI port maxes out at 1920x1200. You're going to need to grab an adapter to go from Mini-Displayport to either dual-link DVI or Displayport, which are both supported by the Dell.

Now, the Thunderbolt display can't directly output Mini-Displayport for boring technical reasons [(see question 20)](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5219?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US). There must be a non-display Thunderbolt device between the display and the adapter I mentioned above. The cheapest example I've found is the Seagate GoFlex Desk Thunderbolt Adapter (STAE122), which has two Thunderbolt ports for daisychaining and retails for about $180.

The full chain:
Mac Mini -> Thunderbolt Display -> STAE122 -> MiniDP to DP or DL-DVI adapter -> Dell monitor

Comment: Fantastic. I followed your advice here and it works perfectly.  I now have a 2560 x 1440 on Thunderbolt and Dell Ultrasharp.  Thank you. An ideal and most economical solution.